# Removing Duplicates Nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes

I am getting multiples nodes by

```
MATCH(n:Employee{name:"Govind Singh"}) return (n);
```

actually by mistake i have created duplicates Nodes.

Now I want to delete all duplicates nodes Except One.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the duplicate nodes are all equivalent and don't have relationships:

```
MATCH (n:Employee {name: "Govind Singh"})
WITH n
SKIP 1
DELETE n
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways to do this, I just came up with this off of the top of my head.  I created a bunch of Govind Singh's, and this appears to work:

```
MATCH(n:Employee{name:"Govind Singh"}) 
WITH max(id(n)) as justOneOfThem 
MATCH(n:Employee{name:"Govind Singh"}) 
WHERE id(n)<>justOneOfThem
DELETE n;
```

When you say "delete duplicate nodes", I interpret this to mean "delete all except one chosen".   I'm somewhat arbitrarily choosing here that whichever one has the highest internal ID gets to stay.  (The internal IDs mean nothing, don't read anything into the meaning of that choice).   So I find all Govind Singh's, figure out which one has the highest ID, then I use that in a second match to find them all again and delete anybody that doesn't have that ID.